# Export Wikipedia article to get summary information

Tags: c#, regex, mediawiki

I'm trying to get introduction from wikipedia article to include it into report. 
For example, for this article: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAP3K8

I want to get:

> Mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 8 is an enzyme that
>   in humans is encoded by the MAP3K8 gene.    This gene was identified
>   by its oncogenic transforming activity in cells.     The encoded
>   protein is a member of the serine/threonine protein kinase family.
>   This kinase can activate both the MAP kinase and JNK kinase pathways. 
>   This kinase was shown to activate IkappaB kinases, and thus induce the
>   nuclear production of NF-kappaB.     This kinase was also found to
>   promote the production of TNF-alpha and IL-2 during T lymphocyte
>   activation. Studies of a similar gene in rat suggested the direct
>   involvement of this kinase in the proteolysis of NF-kappaB1,p105
>   (NFKB1).     This gene may also utilize a downstream in-frame
>   translation start codon, and thus produce an isoform containing a
>   shorter N-terminus.     The shorter isoform has been shown to display
>   weaker transforming activity.    In mice, this gene is known as Tpl2
>   and it is a tumor suppressor gene whose absence contributes to the
>   development and progression of cancer.

I'm getting the page with this URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export/MAP3K8

And I convert the code from this post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1066507.aspx/1 into C#:

```
   HttpWebRequest request  =(HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export/MAP3K8");
   request.Accept = "text/hmtl";
   request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
   Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
   XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(responseStream);
   String NS = "http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.8/";
   XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(reader);
   reader.Close();
   response.Close();
   XPathNavigator myxpathnav = doc.CreateNavigator();
   XPathNodeIterator nodesText = myxpathnav.SelectDescendants("text", NS, false);
   while (nodesText.MoveNext())
   {
       ViewBag.Message += nodesText.Current.InnerXml;
   }
   ViewBag.Summary = getSummary(ViewBag.Message);
   return View();
```

getSummary method, According to PBB template: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:PBB_Controls

I only want to get informations for proteins, if this is following this.

```
   public string getSummary(string page)
    {
        string res = "";
        //The introduction is in 2 parts: 
        //1st between "{{PBB|geneid=1326}}" and &lt;!-- The PBB_Summary (.)* --&gt;
        string intro = "";
        //2nd between "summary_text =" and "=="
        //http://en.wik    ipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export/MAP3K8 is used as example

        string summary = "";
        try
        {
            intro = page.Split(new string[] { "}}" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

            intro = intro.Split(new string[] { "&lt;!--" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
            intro = deleteMediaWikiTag(intro);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            intro = "";
        }
        try
        {
            summary += page.Split(new string[] { "summary_text =" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
            summary = summary.Split(new string[] { "==" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
            summary = deleteMediaWikiTag(summary);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            summary = "";
        }
        res = intro + "\n\n" + summary;
        return res;
    }

   public string deleteMediaWikiTag(string text)
    {
        string res = "";
        // this is working well
        Regex reg = new Regex("{{.*(}})*|{{|}}|'''|&lt;!--.*--&gt;|]]|([[]){2}");
        res = reg.Replace(text,"");
        //I don't understand what is wrong with this regex
        Regex regprime = new Regex("&lt(.)*(&gt;){1}");
        res = regprime.Replace(res, "PRIME");
        return res;
    }
```

My problem is in the execution of `deleteMediaWikiTag(summary)` because I'm losing the end of the summary part which is :

> In mice, this gene is known as Tpl2 and it is a tumor suppressor gene whose absence contributes to the development and progression of cancer.

Before to be handled by the regex, this text looks like:

```
   &lt;ref name=&quot;entrez&quot; /&gt; 
   In mice, this gene is known as Tpl2 and it is a tumor suppressor gene whose absence contributes to the development and progression of cancer.
   &lt;ref&gt;{{cite web|last=DeCicco-Skinner|first=Kathleen|title=Loss of tumor progression locus 2 (tpl2) enhances tumorigenesis and inflammation in two-stage skin carcinogenesis|url=http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3460638/}}&lt;/ref&gt;
```

So according to my regex, I'm expecting something like: (PRIME is used to highlight matches, at the end, I will delete everything matching my regex)

```
   PRIME In  mice *.....* PRIME
```

But I get:

```
   PRIME
```

So this `"&lt(.)*(&gt;){1}"` is matching with the whole part (the first &lt and the last > but I'm asking for a match with only one time the pattern > which is more than one time if I take everything...

What is wrong with this Regex? Did I miss something? Maybe is it a better way to parse this? (but none of the parsers I've found convinced me)

P.S. My parser works with: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFKB2 or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APOA4 but I want to do it more reliably.

Comment: You shouldn't be parsing XML with regex.  Try using a parser like [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Comment: I fixed my issue for this page by changing the Regex into:

>"&lt(.)*(/&gt;){1}|&lt(.)*(&gt;){1}"

I will test more pages with my parser to know if I forgot mediawiki markups but if someone can explain me why the first version wasn't working, it would be a good lesson.

Comment: Have you tried using the "Yahoo abstracts" dumps at download.wikimedia.org?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really can't find any issue with the exiting one. Both the Regular expressions are working fine. I would recommend to use the regular expression online tester before implementing in the code. Try this out: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/